# mysql case statement

Tags: php, mysql, case

can i use 'AND' in the mysql case statement

for example:

```
$d = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_timeslot, date_book, id_beautician

     ,coalesce(thera_b, 'available') AS thera_b

    FROM ( SELECT t.id_timeslot, p.id_beautician, b.date_book

    , MAX(CASE b.id_beautician WHEN 2 THEN 'booked' THEN 'booked' ELSE NULL END 
       AND 
       CASE b.date_book WHEN '2011-01-04' THEN 'booked' ELSE NULL END) AS thera_b

    FROM timeslot as t
    LEFT JOIN bookslot as b ON b.id_timeslot = t.id_timeslot
    LEFT JOIN beautician as p ON p.id_beautician = b.id_beautician
        GROUP BY t.id_timeslot) AS xx");
```

or any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
MAX(CASE WHEN b.id_beautician =2 
   AND b.date_book = '2011-01-04' THEN 'booked' END )  AS thera_b
```

This uses the `searched` case format (second one in [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)) and leaves out the `ELSE NULL` as this is implicit anyway.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do then. Giving source code that doesn't work without explanation and leaving us to guess your intent probably isn't the most productive approach!

Comment: MAX(CASE WHEN b.id_beautician=2 AND b.date_book = '$search_date' THEN 'booked' END) AS thera_b

Comment: sorry my bad! this is from my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512784/php-booking-timeslot.

Comment: Doesn't help me at least. Can you add sample data and example desired result to your question.

Comment: it sorted :) .. i missed comma in the code lol.. :D thanks m8 ;)